# Using C++ DLL in Delphi 6

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, dll, delphi-6

I have to use an encoding function from an external C++ DLL in Delphi 6.
Following is the declaration provided :

`long <Function Name> (char *Data, long &Apply, char *ReturnVal, long &Size)`

Data is the input value, Apply is a boolean value (default : FALSE), ReturnVal is the return value from the DLL and Size is the length of the ReturnVal.

To use this in Delphi 6, I wrote following Code:

```
implementation
   const
     EncoderDLL = '<DLL NAME>';
     FunctionName = 'FUNCTION NAME';
   var
      _TEST : function(const Data : PChar; Apply : PInteger;stOutput : Pchar;
          iSize : PInteger) : integer; stdcall;
   .....
   .....
   var
     stInput,stOutput : string;
     iLength,i1,iResult : integer;
     hnd : THandle;
   begin
     iLength := 0;
     i1 := 0;
     stInput := Trim(edtInput.Text);
     hnd := SafeLoadLibrary(EncoderDLL);
     if hnd > 0 then
     begin
       @_TEST := GetProcAddress(hnd,FunctionName);
       if @_TEST <> nil then
       begin
         iResult := _TEST(PChar(stInput),@i1,PChar(StOutput),@iLength); // ERROR
       end;
     end;
     FreeLibrary(hnd);
  end;
```

I am getting **Access Violation** in the line having 'ERROR' as comments.

If I replace **PChar** in the function declaration with **string**, then the access violation does not come at the same line. It comes while freeing the library. Also, the value of the iLength parameter is populated correctly.

Can anyone please provide pointers to resolve this issue.

Comment: Apply is a reference in the C++. And references cannot be nil. So the translation should be `var Apply: Integer`. And likewise for the `Size` param.

Comment: `function(Data: PChar; var Apply: Longint; ReturnVal: PChar; var Size: Longint): Longint; stdcall;` ?

Comment: @TLama Right. But we have no idea at all what the calling convention is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep PChar, and initialize StOutput to a non-empty string (of a sufficient length) before the call.

Answer (score 3):

1. Are you sure about stdcall convention? If there are no clear instructions in C++ text (like WINAPI, __stdcall etc), then use cdecl.
2. 'const' before Data is not needed
3. allocate memory for StOutput

Comment: thanks. allocating memory for stOutput works. the calling convention is stdcall.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `ReturnVal` is an output parameter (the function fills it in). You should reserve memory for this string in your code. But how much memory should you reserve? There's a common pattern for such functions. **You call the function twice**.

In the **first call** you set `ReturnVal` to `nil` and the function fills in what size it needs in the `Size` parameter.

You then reserve that much memory in your `StOutput` buffer and call the function again. This time you get the result.

```
iResult := _TEST(PChar(stInput),@i1,nil,@iLength); // First call
SetLength( stOutput, iLength ); // reserve memory
iResult := _TEST(PChar(stInput),@i1,PChar(stOutput),@iLength); // Second call
```

Note that this function may or may not follow this convention. But if it doesn't, there's really no way to tell how much memory you should reserve for the output parameter.

Another thing to note is the calling convention. C And C++ functions default to `cdecl` and the declaration you've shown doesn't say otherwise. You've declared it as `stdcall` in Pascal. They should match.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But, if I pass nil for the first time, then also I am encountering the access violation. After setting the length of the stoutput and calling the function. It works. Thanks again

Comment: Then I don't get why the `Size` parameter is referenced. It really feels like you should do what Alex guessed here.

Comment: @Abhineet, have you tried to allocate insufficient buffer size at the first call (e.g. 1 char) ? I'm wondering if the function returns the needed size then.

Comment: @TLama : I made the buffer size to 1 character. then also, function is returning the same desired value of the size variable.

Comment: The interface you're using is poorly designed. Allocate a large buffer and hope it's enough...